# Binding columns based on common IDs (duplicated in one dataframe)

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

$data1

| Sample | Gene |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | gene_1 |
| 2 | gene_1 |
| 3 | gene_2 |
| 4 | gene_3 |
| 5 | gene_3 |

$data2

| Gene | Function | Metabolism |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gene_1 | function_1 | meta_1 |
| gene_2 | function_2 | meta_2 |
| gene_3 | function_3 | meta_3 |

$output desired

| Sample | Gene | Function | Metabolism |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gene_1 | function_1 | meta_1 |
| 2 | gene_1 | function_1 | meta_1 |
| 3 | gene_2 | function_2 | meta_2 |
| 4 | gene_3 | function_3 | meta_3 |
| 5 | gene_3 | function_3 | meta_3 |

I tried with dplyr left_join

output <- left_join(data1, data2, by = "Gene")

but did not give me the right output

Answer (score 1):

Using a right join you could do:

```r
dplyr::right_join(data1, data2)
#> Joining, by = "Gene"
#>   Sample   Gene   Function Metabolism
#> 1      1 gene_1 function_1     meta_1
#> 2      2 gene_1 function_1     meta_1
#> 3      3 gene_2 function_2     meta_2
#> 4      4 gene_3 function_3     meta_3
#> 5      5 gene_3 function_3     meta_3
```

**DATA**

```
data1 <- data.frame(
  Sample = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
  Gene = c(
    "gene_1",
    "gene_1", "gene_2", "gene_3", "gene_3"
  )
)

data2 <- data.frame(
  Gene = c("gene_1", "gene_2", "gene_3"),
  Function = c("function_1", "function_2", "function_3"),
  Metabolism = c("meta_1", "meta_2", "meta_3")
)
```